# Tomcat 7 not setup properly in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

[image]

I downloaded the [32-bit Windows zip](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.35/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86.zip) from Apache's website.
Then I extracted the contents and placed it in my `Program Files` folder where `Eclipse`'s extract is also present.

Then I fired up Eclipse, used the `Servers` tab to set up the server, started it.
I get this:
[image]

However when I try `http://localhost:8080` in Chrome, I get the 404 error.
Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup does work. Tomcat does work. The 404 you see is given by tomcat.

Only problem, you didn't put any index file... your servlet container needs some content!

Answer (score 1):

Even i m facing the same problem discussed above. I am unable to run any app including servlet application with index file.

I found the below mentioned information in some website..

"Eclipse forgets to copy the default apps (ROOT, examples, etc.) when it creates a Tomcat folder inside the Eclipse workspace. Go to C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.34\webapps, R-click on the ROOT folder and copy it. Then go to your Eclipse workspace, go to the .metadata folder, and search for "wtpwebapps". You should find something like your-eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps (or .../tmp1/wtpwebapps if you already had another server registered in Eclipse). Go to the wtpwebapps folder, R-click, and paste ROOT (say "yes" if asked if you want to merge/replace folders/files). "

But the problem is the temp0 folder is empty and i m unable to find the the deploy path ie wtpwebapps. If anyone has come across the same problem and come out with a solution pls let me know..